# Should I use plural nouns in this sentence?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I have come across this situation many times. For example:

> Interactive e-books can not only show characters' movement**s** and facial expression**s** but also can let the children (readers) choose what would they do under the scenario**s**.

Should I use plural for those words? I feel it may not be necessary but characters have many movements and facial expressions in an e-book and there are many scenarios in an e-book too.

I tried searching Google for it but I cannot find explanations for this kind of situation.

Comment: In your example, it's relatively straightforward: there are plural _characters,_ and each will have its own _expression_ and _movement;_ also, there is clearly more than one scenario, since there are plural _ebooks._ Plurals are correct in your sentence, as you have them. (For the plural of _scenario,_ see [**here.**](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/11775/192771))

Answer (score 1):

"movements" is correct, since each character would have more than one movement.

"facial expressions" is also correct, for the same reason.

"under the scenarios" is wrong.  "the" implies singular; only one.  I would re-write this as "under each scenario", since such adventures follow only one scenario at a time.